# Core Data Application design

Tags: macos, core-data, datasource, nsviewcontroller

---

Hello everyone,

I have a question concerning an app I'm developing for Mac OS X right now that uses a simple sqlite database. My question is how should I handle the datasource component into my app ?
Is there a simple way of making one datasource available from within different view controllers other than by using delegates that send messages to the AppDelegate ?
This might seem an odd question but the fact is that I have been developping on IOS only before and you only had to pass the objectcontext to the viewController to make it available to the view controller. On MacosX, I cannot figure out how to do the same...

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: Why would that not work on OSX? You can use the managed object context just like in iOS.

Comment: @Mundi ok but how do I pass it from one viewcontroller to another one ? Do I need to create an object in interface builder pointing to the datasource for each viewcontroller ? An how to do it in code please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to pass the context from one view controller to another:

```
newViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Alternatively, you can keep the context in the app delegate and override `initWithCoder` which  should be called when a view controller is initialised from storyboard or xib:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*) [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
self.managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext;
```

Comment: Thanks a million dude, you rock !

Comment: Just a remark: Shouldn't it be `NSApplication`, if the question is about OS X apps?

Comment: Right, cocoa is different.

Comment: Just one thing to add. I had thought of solution 1) before but it didn't work at first cause you need to declare a managedObjectContext property in the .h file of the target viewcontroller that receives the AppDelegate's managedObjectContext.